# Software to simulate behavioral economic models?

Tags: simulation, octave

I am looking for a way to simulate behavioral economic models to illustrate the effects of changing parameters. I am familiar with statistical analysis (especially R), but I only have few programming skills beyond R. I think that if there is a way to achieve my goal (I'm not really sure if it is possible at all!) that Octave should be a good choice.

Usually such a model defines some kind of game with actions, strategies and payoffs for every player. Then these actions get evaluated and normally an equilibrium between the players actions/strategies is determined.

One of my desired models is Rabin's idea of Fairness Equilibria. Pages 1286ff can give a short idea of how Rabin defines the game and determines the equilibrium. [LINK](http://pascal.iseg.utl.pt/~depeco/summerschool2007/Rabin.pdf)

My goal is to have a function that depicts that model and enables me to illustrate the effects of different assumptions and situations within the frame of the specific model.

So my question is: Is it possible at all? Is Octave suitable or should I choose another language/environment?

Thanks in advance for any sort of advice!

EDIT:

I try to sketch the model:

Starting point is a two player normal form game (Prisoner's Dilemma) with the strategy sets $S_1, S_2$ for every player from which they choose their actions. The payoff function for each player is defined as $\pi_i = S_1 \times S_2$. So player $i$ chooses action $a_i \in S_i$. Now player $j$ has a believe about $i$'s strategy $b_i \in S_i$ and player $i$ has a belief about player $j$'s belief about $i$'s strategy $c_i \in S_i$. 
So the feasible payoffs for $i$ depending on his beliefs are in the set $\Pi(b_j) = \{(\pi_i(a_i,b_j),\pi_j(b_j,a_i)) | a_i \in S_i\}$

That's the framework.

The routine now has to determine

- $\pi_j^h(b_j)$ as the highest payoff for $j$ depending on $i$'s belief that is Pareto efficient in $\Pi(b_j)$
- $\pi_j^l(b_j)$ as the lowest payoff for $j$ depending on $i$'s belief that is Pareto efficient in $\Pi(b_j)$
- $\pi_j^{min}(b_j)$ as the worst possible payoff for $j$ depending on $i$'s belief
- the reference point for $j$: $\pi_j^e(b_j) = \frac{\pi_j^h(b_j) + \pi_j^l(b_j)}{2}$
- the kindness of $i$ towards $j$: $\kappa_i(a_i,b_j)=\frac{\pi_j(b_j,a_i) - \pi_j^e(b_j)}{\pi_j^h(b_j) - \pi_j^{min}(b_j)}$
- believed kindness of $j$ towards $i$: $\bar\kappa_j(b_j,c_i)=\frac{\pi_i(c_i,b_j) - \pi_i^e(c_i)}{\pi_i^h(c_i) - \pi_i^{min}(c_i)}$

Then the Expected Utility is defined as: $U_i(a_i,b_j,c_i) = \pi(a_i,b_j) + \bar\kappa_j(b_j,c_i) \cdot [1+\kappa_i(a_i,b_j)]$

Now, to be a Fairness Equilibrium, a pair of strategies $(a_1^*,a_2^*)$ has to fulfill following conditions:

1. $a_i^* \in \text{argmax}_{a_i \in S_i} U_i(a_i,b_j,c_i)$
2. $c_i = b_j = a_i^*$

So my goal is to get a routine that determines these Fairness Equilibria when a certain game is given.

Comment: I'm sure either R or Octave would be fine, but lacking an idea of what the model needs to compute it's hard to say for sure. You should describe the model in the question text. People (myself included) aren't going to take the time to read the paper in order to answer your question.

Comment: What types of computations do you need to perform? Do you have to do some optimization (specifically, something like nonlinear programming)? In general, I tend to recommend Python due to the sheer number of libraries, but I don't have a clear idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well the task is to find that action, that maximizes the utility function. When you solve that model manually, you just determine the utility for every pair of strategies and look which pair results in the highest utility. So it isn't really hard to solve, but I don't have an idea how to develop such a routine...